# Printing out value in loop

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

Hey guys Im new to ComArch. Im writing a homework assignment. My question is i have this loop in my program that divides a users int input by 10 and my loop will  go through the and divide until the quotient is at 0 . Currently it prints out 0 for my quotient but doest print out each value of the remainder. So how would i modify my code to print out every single remainder that is  left over after dividing.

```
loop:
    li $s0, 10    #divisor

    div $t0,$s0 #divide input by 10
    mflo $t0    #quotiant 
    mfhi $t3        #remainder
    sw $t3, ($t1)   #stores emainder into address of int_a
    addi $t1,$t1,4  #increases the pointer
 bne  $t0,0,loop
```

Comment: You have to do a system call for printing the output

Comment: Where would that occur? Outside the loop?

Comment: Since you want to print each value of remainder, therefore it will be inside the loop of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find in the [MIPS Architecture and Assembly Language Overview](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm) the section "[System Calls and I/O (SPIM Simulator)](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm#IOSystemCalls)" which details how to print a value.

In your case, within the loop, you would have to print `$t3`.

```
li  $v0, 1          # load appropriate system call code into register $v0;
                    # code for printing integer is 1
move    $a0, $t3    # move integer to be printed into $a0:  $a0 = $t3
syscall             # call operating system to perform operation
```

Comment: Ok thanks. One more thing. Since Im just printing out each remainder each division. which remainder is save in the address of my defined array ? all, the first remainder or last remainder?

Comment: @AbrahamCarmona `$t3` only keep the last remainder once the loop complete.

Comment: So just to get some direction. I would have to create a new loop where in stores each remainder in some address? correct? @vonC

Comment: @AbrahamCarmona you could include that storing step in the loop itself, because the remainders would be lost once the loop completes.

Comment: Got it. Very Very helpful. Actually more helpful then my TA . Thanks